Help using .srv files with MicroROS esp-idf-component
My MicroROS project uses the microros_espidf_component and I am trying to implement a .srv file as part of another espidf component. I understand the how the server is implemented and have walked through the addtwoints server.
My problem is that I have implemented server as a separate espidf component, and as such I am having problems getting find_package to locate ament_cmake and rosidl_default_generators so that my .srv file can be used to create the source code files.
my CMakeFile.txt has
Added dependancy on the microros component with
add_dependencies(libROSMicroPyESPCAM  micro_ros_espidf_component espressif/esp32-camera)
Augmented the path to point directly to the files
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH  ${MICROROS_DIR}/micro_ros_src/install/share/rosidl_default_generators/cmake/ ${MICROROS_DIR}/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ ${MICROROS_DIR}/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake ${MICROROS_DIR}/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake_libraries/share/ament_cmake_libraries/cmake ) message("CMake Module ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
list( APPEND ament_cmake_DIR ${MICROROS_DIR}/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake/cmake/) message("Ament CMake ${ament_cmake_DIR}")
It seems to find parts of the packages but never fully satisfies all the requirements, here is the output.
CMake Module /opt/esp/idf/tools/cmake;/opt/esp/idf/tools/cmake/third_party;/opt/rosmicropy/components/micro_ros_espidf_component/micro_ros_src/install/share/rosidl_default_generators/cmake/;/opt/rosmicropy/components/micro_ros_espidf_component/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake/cmake/;/opt/rosmicropy/components/micro_ros_espidf_component/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake;/opt/rosmicropy/components/micro_ros_espidf_component/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake_libraries/share/ament_cmake_libraries/cmake
Ament CMake /opt/rosmicropy/components/micro_ros_espidf_component/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake/cmake/
-- Found ament_cmake: 1.3.9 (/opt/rosmicropy/components/micro_ros_espidf_component/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake/cmake/)
CMake Error at /opt/rosmicropy/components/micro_ros_espidf_component/micro_ros_dev/install/ament_cmake/share/ament_cmake/cmake/ament_cmake_export_dependencies-extras.cmake:5 (find_package):
By not providing "Findament_cmake_libraries.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH
this project has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided
by "ament_cmake_libraries", but CMake did not find one.
Could not find a package configuration file provided by
"ament_cmake_libraries" with any of the following names:
ament_cmake_librariesConfig.cmake
ament_cmake_libraries-config.cmake
Add the installation prefix of "ament_cmake_libraries" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
or set "ament_cmake_libraries_DIR" to a directory containing one of the
above files.  If "ament_cmake_libraries" provides a separate development
package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.***
Here is my CMake code that tries to run the compiler
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)
rosidl_generate_interfaces(libROSMicroPyESPCAM
"interfaces/srv/Image.srv"
)
Is there a file that I can include to set up the CMAKE_MODULE_PATH for me ??
Thank you
-John
